# Using px vs dp in xml files for inhouse device

Tags: android, layout

I'm having difficulty at work convincing people that I like to use px over dp for our inhouse device because we are not programming to different phones/tablets. We have 2 inhouse devices with 1280 and 1980 width pixels. I programmaticaly find out the width of the device and set the correct xml file.

Is there any reason why I should use dp over px for us?

The way I see it, I can be a lot more accurate using px and the dev time is lower because I don't have to think in dp. Technically Android converts all dp to px so it should be faster, but I doubt its that much faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Choose DP for extendibility. Rarely can you ever know for sure that the requirements are fixed for the life of your product. Plan for the unknown.

Comment: From my own experience I found that even using DP, it doesn't work well across devices. As for our devices, I am creating different xml layouts that are loaded at runtime depending on the width of the screen, so I don't see what unknown I should be planning for. Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: My point is that you don't want to have to redo your layouts if you need to support a new screen width. For example what if you get a high pixel density screen that you need to support. You just don't know what might change.